# android alarm manager triggers after time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I realize that this [alarm triggers even after finish time in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505036/alarm-triggers-even-after-finish-time-in-android)  is a similar question. However, mine's got a little bit different.

I wonder, for example, if i set time to be 14:40, and launch the app at 15:00 (or any other time after 14:40:00), the alarm manager's onReceive method will be triggered immediately.

Actually, this is a confirmation rather than a question since my application seems to do this.

Thank you !

**CODE**

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    //System.out.println();

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Comment: @Haresh Here's my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the [AlarmManager.setExact()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

```
  AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Actually I kinda want that "immediately trigger" thing happens. But thanks! I learn this now